# How can you use Ln function in C programing?

Tags: c

Header file math.h is for mathematical functions like cos,sin, tan..
But how to write the ln function and not log?

Comment: Why? Ln is just log base *e*.

Comment: log base e *is* [`log`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log). What you're thinking of as log (log base 10) is `log10` in the library.

Comment: You could use the taylor series or paulo's formula

Comment: Don't you mean log base e is Ln? Or am I confused?

Comment: no, I mean that the standard library function called `log` computes log base e.

Comment: OK, thanks. :) I'm more of a math/physics guy than a CS guy, so I didn't actually know that. :D

Comment: Thankyou guys. Very helpful

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The C function [`log`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log) is the natural logarithm, which mathematicians usually write as "ln".

The C function [`log10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log10) is the logarithm base 10, which is sometimes written "log".

Answer (score 5):

Remember math at school: logA_B = logA_C/logB_C

Answer (score 1):

```
double ln(double x) { return log(x); }
```

Or in a pinch

```
#define ln(x) log(x)
```