# How to avoid floating point exception when using pow?

Tags: c, floating-point, numerical, floating-point-exceptions

I use a C library which uses the `pow` function on two `double` values

```
double a = pow(b, c)
```

At the moment, I have `b = 0.62` and `c = 1504`, which means that `a` should be nearly 0 (3.6e-312).

But I have a floating point exception. How to avoid it and directly return 0? Can we anticipate this case?

I use Debian 9, 64-bit, and I compile with gcc 6.3. The library is [ccmaes](https://github.com/CMA-ES/c-cmaes) and here is the problematic line:

https://github.com/CMA-ES/c-cmaes/blob/eda8268ee4c8c9fbe4d2489555ae08f8a8c949b5/src/cmaes.c#L893

I have used gdb so the floating point exception does not come from the division (t->chiN = 2.74)

If I try to reproduce it, with the values when the FPE occurs, I have no problem (compilation option : -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC   -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wconversion -o, like the library)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double psxps = 5.6107247793270769;
    double cs = 0.37564049253818982;
    int gen = 752;
    double chiN = 2.7421432615656891;
    int N =8;
    double foo =  sqrt(psxps) / sqrt(1. - pow(1.-cs, 2*gen)) / chiN 
      < 1.4 + 2./(N+1);
    printf("%lf\n",foo);
}
```

Result: 1.00000000000

Comment: What is an FPE?

Comment: @machine_1 I would guess "floating point exception".

Comment: Please post [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure your exception is due to this line?
When I try at home your exact example I get 5.71612e-313.
Can you give more details about the library you use for "pow", the compiler you use, on what system, etc? Perhaps you should try to upgrade something. Floating-point exceptions are mostly due to divisions by 0.

Comment: In addition to a minimal, complete, verifiable example, what platform are you running on—hardware, compiler, operating system, including versions? `pow(.62, 1504)` is representable in the common 64-bit `double` format. It is subnormal, but even implementations that flush subnormals to zero ought to return a result for this, not trap.

Comment: Ok, I use Debian 9 64 bits and I compile with gcc 6.3. The library is c cmaes and here is the problematic line: https://github.com/CMA-ES/c-cmaes/blob/eda8268ee4c8c9fbe4d2489555ae08f8a8c949b5/src/cmaes.c#L893

Comment: This "problematic line" is containing division. Which can give division by zero. I have no idea how you deduced the problem is in `pow`.

Comment: I have used gdb

Comment: If you take the lines you presented in the question, give it the values you presented in the question and compile it with the compiler you state in the question - does it give you the exception?

Comment: About the edit:  there are *two* divisions. I don't understand how this question is getting so many upvotes as it is most likely completely misleading.

Comment: I know it is in the pow because of gdb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163808/discussion-between-antoinemazuyer-and-eugene-sh).

Comment: Is the code you posted supposed to result in a floating point exception?

Comment: No It works whereas it is the same values given by gdb when I run the library from which this line is taken. I have a FPE using the library, but it works like a charm using the code sample

Comment: The snippet you posted is a bit different from the "offending" line in the linked code, which is basically `int hsign = /*some calc with doubles*/ < /*some double value*/ `.

Comment: i suspect FPE is overflow due to division by small number (maybe 0) and not anyhing to do with pow() troubles.  break the line of code into steps to see the true culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually at least, `pow(b, c)` can be considered as being implemented as `exp(c * ln(b))`.

So one way of intercepting a potential numerical problem would be to compute the first part of this conceptual `pow` yourself, using

```
double i = ln(b);
```

If `c * i` is sufficiently small (the threshold value will be a function of the floating point scheme used on your platform), then you can proceed with the evaluation of `pow` using the C standard library function.

It's probably unwise to finish the job yourself with `exp(c * i)`, since the standard `pow` function may well have various tricks up its sleeve to attain a result superior in accuracy to `exp(c * ln(b))`.

Comment: Don't you mean `ln` instead of `log`?

Comment: @stackptr: Oops.

Comment: @Bathsheba: A `pow` implementation generally uses logarithms and exponents, but it is more likely to use base two (to match the base of the floating-point format) and specialized code to calculate the things it needs, rather than calling the actual `exp`, `exp2`, `ln`, or `log2`. Those routines would not provide the needed precision for a good `pow`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: A good point, as always. I wonder if it's feasible to still proceed as above, check c * i, and if that satisfies some criteria or other, call the standard pow function.

Comment: in c language, log is ln (and log10 is log) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205208/how-can-you-use-ln-function-in-c-programing

Comment: `pow()` as `exp(c * ln(b))` when 1) `b <= 0` 2) is unnessisarially imprecise,

Comment: Do not implement pow in terms of exp and ln. It will introduce a loss of precision and will likely be slower.

Comment: @PaulFloyd: I might reword this.

Comment: @PaulFloyd: Dunnit. Obviously this invalidates some of the previous comments, but the edit history is always viewable.

Comment: I would suggest that before anyone tries to do better than their libc version of pow that they take a look at the source https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_pow.c and https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/msun/src/e_powf.c.